# Mosaic plot: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am engaging in a project about the relationship btw perception of voters and their voting behavior

The x variable - perception (PQ8_W3) is categorical variables with 4 values:

- (1) winner
- (2) loser
- (3) can't say
- (9) don't know

whereas y variable (same) is a 1/0 dummy.

I know x is a factor and I tried to change it to numeric, but I still cannot generate the mosaic graph. Also, I changed 9 to 4 so as to make it into continuous, but still doesn't work out.

Here is the dput data

```
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "9"), class = "factor")
```

This is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)
# here is fine, but I want to change the x and y variables 
ggplot(data = AfD) + geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(same), fill=PQ8_W3), na.rm=TRUE)  
# the error message comes out here, the console just gives me "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"
ggplot(data = AfD) + geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(PQ8_W3), fill=(same), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Where is the `product` function from and what does it do? Where is `geom_mosaic` from? (It's not in `ggplot2`). What class is `perception`? Factor, numeric, something else? Can you share a little bit of data---just a few rows so we can see the structure? Sharing data with `dput()` is preferred, e.g., `dput(dat[1:10, ])`.

Comment: Markus, thanks for your help. You may download the data set here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HePEQdyyzzQAWsRpQibncMWxkYX6tGsj/view?usp=sharing). The geom_mosaic plot is from (library(ggmosaic)). Class of perception is factor in the first place.

Comment: @PandaChan 1) Please **edit your question** with any additional information. Code in comments is really hard to read, even for people who notice it's there in the first place (not everyone does). 2) You are likely to get help from a wider audience if you include the data in the question itself, e.g. with `dput()` as suggested above. Many of us would hesitate to download data from an unknown link.

Comment: Z. Lin, thank you for your msg. I just edited my comment. Hope I made the dput stuff right, as I am a beginner of R.